# Joining two tables based on non-matching date fields

Tags: sql, join, sas

There are two tables (A and B) that I want to join by date. This is complicated by the fact that the dates do not necessarily line up neatly across tables. That is to say, dates from table B might fall outside or between the entries in table A.

I suspect that there must be an easy way to accomplish this in SQL/SAS, but I’m very new to both and don’t see how. I would be very glad if someone could point me to concrete solutions, examples, or functions that I can use to solve this problem. I created a fictitious case below to illustrate.

This is an example of how table A might look like (for one participant):

```
Table A
-------------------------------------------+
participant start       end
-------------------------------------------+
101         1-1-2010    26-4-2010
101         27-4-2010   2-10-2014
101         3-10-2014   4-1-2015
101         5-1-2015    31-8-2015
101         1-9-2015    12-10-2016
101         13-10-2016  31-12-2018
```

Below is an example of table B that needs to connect to table A. As you can see, the dates differ too much for a simple left join:

```
Table B
---------------------------------------------------------+
participant start_date  end_date    Content
---------------------------------------------------------+
101         1-1-2012    31-8-2012   A
101         1-9-2012    31-8-2013   B
101         1-9-2013    31-8-2014   C
101         1-9-2014    2-10-2014   D
101         3-10-2014   31-8-2015   E
101         1-9-2015    31-1-2016   F
101         1-9-2015    31-1-2016   F
```

The idea for the joined table C is that every row of table A is informed by data from table B. I want to select an entry from B that falls within the span of table A. If several entries from B fit, the most recent one should be used. If table B doesn’t have  information from that period (as is the case in the first row), the closest information should be used. A different way to put it is that I want the most recent information of B added to each  row of A.

```
Table C
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
participant startA      endA        startB      endB        Content
----------------------------------------------------------------------+
101         1-1-2010    26-4-2010   1-1-2012    31-8-2012   A
101         27-4-2010   2-10-2014   1-9-2013    31-8-2014   C
101         3-10-2014   4-1-2015    1-9-2014    2-10-2014   D
101         5-1-2015    31-8-2015   3-10-2014   31-8-2015   E
101         1-9-2015    12-10-2016  1-9-2015    31-1-2016   F
101         13-10-2016  31-12-2018  1-9-2015    31-1-2016   F
```

This is the first time that I’m working with SAS and SQL, so my own efforts work very poorly. Below, I’m joining these two tables in a procedure with several steps: I’m first creating a full join to get all possible (relevant) permutations of table A and B. Then I calculate the date difference between the data from table A and B. Finally, for each period of A, I’m selecting the row where there is minimal difference in dates between the data from the original tables.

```
/* Create outer join of both tables*/
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE work.fulljoin AS
    SELECT a.*, b.* 
    FROM work.table_A AS a
    FULL JOIN work.table_B AS b ON a.participant = b.participant;
quit;

/* Group by ID and entry date of each period */
PROC SORT data=work.fulljoin;
    BY participant startA; 
RUN;

/* Calculate the date differences between tables A and B */
DATA work.fulljoin_wdelta;
    SET work.fulljoin;
    delta=abs(endA-endB);
RUN;

/* Remove unnecessary rows */
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE output.joined AS
    SELECT * FROM work.fulljoin_wdelta
    GROUP BY participant, startA
    HAVING delta=min(delta);
QUIT;
```

However with large datasets (millions of rows in A and B) this becomes prohibitive. Also, this method doesn’t strictly speaking enforce that you will get the most recent B data for every A period, just the one that’s closest in end date.

Comment: Is your table C an example of how you want your joined table to look, or just the best you've managed to produce so far? If it's the latter, please include an example of how you want it to look based on your input tables A and B.

Comment: Are the millions of rows in a SAS data set or a remote database table ? If so, what indexes are on the data set ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! @user667489, Table C is what I want to get out of this.

Richard, this is regarding a SAS data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date range joins can be very complex when you have to deal with ties, maximal coverage versus toe-in-the-water overlaps, etc... You certainly don't want to store the union and intermediaries in the final solution, although they can be helpful while debugging logic.

Here is a correlated sub-query technique that looks up the 'best' content range matching A.  It will have problems if the content data is not distinct `end_date` with in `participant`.

Every `one` row (target) has a lookup done.  The range overlap logic is important

```
      where one.participant = two.participant
        and two.start_date < one.end
        and two.end_date > one.start
```

and allows a content date range to be partially outside the target range.

```
data one;
input participant start: ddmmyy. end: ddmmyy.;

format start end yymmdd10.;

datalines;
101         1-1-2010    26-4-2010
101         27-4-2010   2-10-2014
101         3-10-2014   4-1-2015
101         5-1-2015    31-8-2015
101         1-9-2015    12-10-2016
101         13-10-2016  31-12-2018
;

data two;
input participant start_date: ddmmyy.  end_date: ddmmyy.   Content: $;

format start_date end_date yymmdd10.;

datalines;
101         1-1-2012    31-8-2012   A
101         1-9-2012    31-8-2013   B
101         1-9-2013    31-8-2014   C
101         1-9-2014    2-10-2014   D
101         3-10-2014   31-8-2015   E
101         1-9-2015    31-1-2016   F
101         1-9-2015    31-1-2017   F
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select 
    one.*
  , ( select min(content)
      from two 
      where one.participant = two.participant
        and two.start_date < one.end
        and two.end_date > one.start
      group by participant
      having end_date = max(end_date)
    ) as content
  from
    one
  order by
    participant, start
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: this looks very cool! The range lookup logic is tricky indeed. Can you explain if the min(content) is critical? It seems to select the oldest entry in TWO per row in ONE; if I leave the min() away, it gets me more recent data which I prefer. 

This leads to a second question about this code. The real "TWO" table has many columns. I'm having trouble selecting more than one using this code. Ideally, I would like to state "SELECT * FROM two", but then I get errors about composite expressions in the "ORDER BY participant, start" line. Is there a trick to this?

Comment: When the correlated sub-query matches more than one row there will an error, thus the sub-query is grouped so that it will return the lowest valued `content` when there are two or more one `two` rows having the same highest `end_date`.  Glossed over in *it will have problems*.  Your exploration of using this query approach may discover high resource usage (cpu/disk/time) and a desire to pursue further alternatives.

Comment: A SAS SQL correlated sub-query (CSQ) can deliver with only a 1-tuple (one column) (some databases might allow for n-tuple (multiple selects in the CSQ)) and you have seen it is not suited for replacing a more traditional join that selects multiple columns from `two`.  The query for a robust handling of all date range matchup conditions is not an easy one-off.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation! Didn't know about the tuple limitation.  I think what I'll do is to split the process in parts - use your code to append the correct dates from table two and store them in table one. In the second step I should then be able to left join the rest of table 2, based on the new date column(s). I'll get to work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your existing logic into a single query:

```
proc sql noprint _method;
  create table table_c as
    select 
      a.participant, 
      a.start as start_a, 
      a.end as end_a, 
      b.start_date as start_b, 
      b.end_date as end_b,
      abs(a.end - b.end_date) as delta
    from table_a a inner join table_b b 
    on a.participant = b.participant
    group by a.participant, start_a
    having delta = min(delta)
    ;     
quit;
```

The log output confirms that this performs a hash join as long as you have enough memory:

```
NOTE: SQL execution methods chosen are:

      sqxcrta
          sqxsumg
              sqxsort
                  sqxjhsh
                      sqxsrc( WORK.TABLE_B(alias = B) )
                      sqxsrc( WORK.TABLE_A(alias = A) )
```

If the resulting table is different from what you're trying to produce, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still doing many small steps because I'm getting used to SQL/SAS. This is indeed much more elegant.